Getting Database Envirnment name dynamically in the query
@Repository
public interface GeoDataRepository
extends RevisionRepository<GeoDataEntity, Long, Long>, JpaRepository<GeoDataEntity, Long> {
@Query(value = "SELECT " +
        "    gd.farmer_id as OfisFarmerId," +
        " gd.id as GeodbId," +
        "    gd.data_source as DataSource," +
        "    gd.country as CountryName," +
        " gd.fg_name as FarmerGroupName," +

        "    COALESCE(gd.geographic_unit, 'polygon') as GeoUnitType," +
        " (select get_next_sequence_value()) AS JobId," +
        "    p.ofis_plot_id as PlotId," +
        "    gd.entity_Name_2 as RegionName," +
        "    gd.product as ProductName," +
        "    gd.reference_year as Year," +
        "    gd.is_active as isActive " +
        "FROM " +

        "    geodata_sit.geo_data gd " +
        "    JOIN geodata_sit.farms f ON gd.farmer_id = f.farmer_id_fk" +
        "    JOIN geodata_sit.plots p ON f.ofis_farm_id = p.ofis_farm_id_fk " +
        "  where p.job_id is null " +
        "ORDER BY " +
        "    farmer_id ASC " +
        "LIMIT :initialLoad", nativeQuery = true)
        

List getGeoDataForBigQuery(@Param("initialLoad") Long initialLoad);
}
Current I am working a springboot data jpa application.I am using JPQL where i am using native query.Here in the above query in the FROM clause we are hard coding  geodata_sit where sit is the enviornment name which is hardcoded.My requirement is I need to pass the DB enviornment name dynamically to the query.
Please find the following ServiceImpl class for calling this repository class method
public class BigQueryServiceImpl implements BigQueryService {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlobStorageService.class);

@Autowired
private GeoDataRepository geoDataRepository;

@Autowired
private ErrorLogRepository errorLogRepository;

@Value("${initial.full.load.limit}")
private Long loadLimit;

@Value("${incremental.full.load.limit}")
private Long incrementalLoadLimit;

@Value("${bigquery.dataset}")
private String dataset;

@Value("${bigquery.dataset.table}")
private String table;

@Value("${bigquery.enviornment}")
private String envirnment;



public MessageDTO postDatatoBigquery() {

    MessageDTO result= new MessageDTO();
    try {
      //  List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsListPloygon = geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery(loadLimit);
        List<GeoDataRepository.GeoDataDetails> geoDataDetailsListPloygon = geoDataRepository.getGeoDataForBigQuery(loadLimit,envirnment);
        List<GeoDataDTO> geoDataDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

       geoDataDetailsList = convertInterfacetoDto(geoDataDetailsListPloygon);


        Long lastFarmerId = null;

        int i = geoDataDetailsList.size() - 1;

        GeoDataDTO details = geoDataDetailsList.get(i);

        lastFarmerId = details.getOfisFarmerId();
        logger.info("Last Farmer ID:{} ", lastFarmerId);

        Map<Long, Long> farmerIdCountMap = new HashMap<>();

        farmerIdCountMap=geoDataDetailsList.stream()
                .filter(id -> id != null)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GeoDataDTO::getOfisFarmerId, Collectors.counting()));

        Long count= 0L;
        count = findCount(farmerIdCountMap,lastFarmerId,count);

        int totalFarmerPlotCount=geoDataRepository.getTotalCount(lastFarmerId);
        List<GeoDataDTO> filteredGeoDataList= new ArrayList<>();

        if(totalFarmerPlotCount !=count){
            Long finalLastFarmerId = lastFarmerId;
            filteredGeoDataList=geoDataDetailsList.stream()
                    .filter(detailsList -> !detailsList.getOfisFarmerId().equals(finalLastFarmerId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }else{
            filteredGeoDataList=geoDataDetailsList;
        }

        List<Long> plotIdList = filteredGeoDataList.stream()
                .map(dto -> dto.getPlotId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<GeoDataDTO> finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList= new ArrayList<>();

        Map<Long, String> plotIdGeoMap = new HashMap<>();

        List<Long> plotIdListFinal=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> geoDbIdListFinal=new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long plotId : plotIdList) {
            try {
                String plotGeo = geoDataRepository.getGeoJson(plotId);
                updatePlotData(plotIdGeoMap,plotIdListFinal,plotId,plotGeo);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logError(plotId, details.getJobId(),details.getGeoUnitType(),e.getMessage(),errorType.POLYGANCONVERSION);
            }
        }

        filteredGeoDataList.forEach(dto -> {
            String updatedPlotGeo = plotIdGeoMap.get(dto.getPlotId());
            updateGeoDbIdList(updatedPlotGeo,dto,geoDbIdListFinal,finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList);
        });
        result=insertBq(finalFilteredGeoDataPolygonList);

        Map<Long, GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails> plotIdGeoDataPinMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Long plotId : plotIdList) {
            try {
                GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails plotGeo = geoDataRepository.getGeoJsonPin(plotId);
                if(null != plotGeo) {
                    plotIdGeoDataPinMap.put(plotId, plotGeo);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logError(plotId, details.getJobId(),details.getGeoUnitType(),e.getMessage(),errorType.PINCONVERSION);

            }
        }

        List<GeoDataDTO> finalFilteredGeoDataPinList= new ArrayList<>();

        filteredGeoDataList.forEach(dto -> {
            GeoDataRepository.GeoDataPinDetails updatedPlotGeo = plotIdGeoDataPinMap.get(dto.getPlotId());
            setGeoData(dto,updatedPlotGeo,finalFilteredGeoDataPinList,plotIdList);
        });

         result=insertBq(finalFilteredGeoDataPinList);
         //for testing
         updateGeoPlotData(plotIdListFinal,geoDbIdListFinal,result,plotIdList);
    } catch (BigQueryException e) {
        logger.error("Exception in postDatatoBigquery method - Unable to push data to Big query {}",e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

I have added the envirnment varible in the application.properties file and tried to load the value from application.properties to the query dynamically.
